# Unique CASE ID column

Tags: sharepoint-online, id

I've created a Sharepoint list and would like each record in the list to have a unique identifier, starting with `CASE-`

I am leveraging the Site generated ID column (Hidden in the list view), by creating a new calculated column called `CASE ID' and using formula:

```
="CASE-"&TEXT(ID,"00").
```

Whenever I refresh the formula it works, it will show CASE-01, CASE-02, CASE-03, but the next day it will revert back to CASE-00, CASE-00, CASE-00.

I do have a work-flow running in the back to refresh 'today' date (not sure if that has anything to do with it?)

Does anyone have a solution so that once CASE-01 is set, it doesn't revert to CASE-00?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported to use ID in a calculated column. I have reproduced your issue. When the workflow which is used to update a field value runs, the ID value in calculated field will be changed to '`0`'.

To work around this issue, you need to use a Workflow to get the ID and set it to another field *(e.g. 'itemID')*. Use 'itemID' in the calculated field instead.

1. Create a text field named 'itemID' and hide it in the form. List settings -> Content Types -> Click the content type -> Click the 'itemID' and select 'Hidden'.

   *(If Content Types doesn't appear, click Advanced settings, and click Yes under Allow management of content types?, and then click OK.)*
2. Create a workflow and automatically run it when an item is created.
3. In the workflow, Use 'Set Field in Current Item' action. Set 'itemID' to '`Current Item:ID`'.